# Cannot run npm packages on Azure because of long path name

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, azure-web-app-service

I just wanted to publish my sails.js on Azure. There are some files cannot be uploaded due to file path length of nested modules, and it fails.

Please see SS below;

[image]

Is there any easy workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that npm didn't play nice with the Windows Maximum Path Length limitation.

However, [npm v3.0+](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0) has fixed this issue so that it doesn't create massively long dependency paths anymore.

Comment: Great point! I will update to 3.0 and hopefully it will be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Maximum Path Length Limitation**
 260 characters.